# Uploading file to sharepoint and returning the url of the uploaded file

Tags: laravel, sharepoint, upload, sharepoint-api

I am using laravel trying to upload the file to sharepoint folder and want to return the url of the uploaded file. I have went through the documentation and various article but not feeling comfortable and didnt found any clear ways to acheive it.

Request you to please guide with way to start with.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Comment: Do you use the SharePoint Rest API to Upload the document? Or do you use SharePoint Add-In? It's not clear in your question

Comment: I am trying to use sharepoint rest api but not getting a start point where to start with

Comment: If you're using Sharepoint rest api then you can get it started from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/upload-a-file-by-using-the-rest-api-and-jquery).